# 301 Redirect old domain to new and use the old domain for emails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, g-suite, 301-redirect, dns-hosting

What I want to do:

Part 1. Redirect `old domain` to `new domain`.
Part 2. Use the `old domain` for mails

My current setup:
Both domains are set up with Google Load Balancer and using Google managed SSL.

1. To achieve what I intended to do, is it right to use Google Load Balancer to do the URL redirect from `old domain` to `new domain`?
2. If the above is feasible, do I need to set up the `old domain`'s ssl certificates in the `new domain`'s load balancer? Will it have downtime if is required to do so?
3. Will using this approach affect the MX record?
4. Will it be better if the URL redirect is done on the server level?

Thanks

Comment: HTTP 3xx redirects don't affect MX in any way.

Comment: Redirects for HTTPS require certificates for the old and new domain names. You can do redirects in the load balancer, but I prefer to implement redirects at the webserver. HTTP redirects do not affect the SMTP protocol or MX resource records.

Answer (score 0):

Hi as i know you want to redirect some-old.com to some-new.com, and use some-old.com as mail handler.

First, you need to know that website configuration and mail configuration is two different things, you can change website configuration like webserver, LB, SSL without interfere with mail operations.

So bassicaly you need 2 configuration:

1. Redirecting Old URL Via Webserver / LB
2. DNS Configuration on some-old.com for MX Record.

Back to your questions, this is my answer :

1. Yes, its posibble to do that, you need to make sure the some-new.com already pointed to Google LB IP Address.
2. Yes, you need to set up some-new.com with new SSL Cert, the old one's can't be used on the new domains. And for the downtime will happen when you restart / reload the Load Balance services to apply the configuration, and i think it will be pretty fast.
3. No, Since you still used the some-old.com for your email, you don't need to change MX Record on Google DNS.
4. Back to Point 1, if your some-old.com pointed to Google LB you just need do it in LB configuration, thats it.

Hope this will help